# Which Node.js framework should I use to add a backend to my existing React project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nosql

I'm a frontend developer by trade. I have a new brand personal project that I set up with Create React App. It's running React version 18, and it's written with React hooks (duh). I'm using Base Web as the component library, although I'm not married to it. I'm using Redux for the UI state management.

Now that the UI / UX is starting to take shape, I'm getting more ambitious. I'm ready to grow this from a toy / portfolio piece into a real app. I need a database. I need to have user accounts. I'd like to do some realtime stuff with web sockets, too. I'm pretty rusty at database stuff. My most recent experience was with MongoDB. I used to use MySQL back in the day, so I know SQL basics, though I'm quite rusty. I don't have a strong opinion about SQL vs NoSQL. The nature of the app is a personal organizer with to-dos, calendars, reminders, etc. (Just so you have an idea of the kind of data I'll be working with).

I'm trying to decide on what DB to use and what Node.js framework to use. Express is familiar to me, but it seems a bit dated. I'd ideally like a solution that is "batteries included," as opposed to picking out the various pieces of the backend stack and wiring them up by hand. I'm currently researching HAPI. Given what I've described, can anyone recommend a good stack? Thank you so much!

Comment: Firebase is a really good option if you are OK with JSON-style DBs

Comment: @HittuDesai thank you. That's on my list to research.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a lot of things that you should consider before making a decision. I am going to try to highlight as many as possible.

Firstly, I would ask if you need SEO for your application? If yes, then you should move your react app to `NextJS`. It is pretty cool and offers a lot of advantages over the traditionally used `react` app created using `create-react-app`. It comes with a solution to define your own API's. And if you want to try something nee you can try the new  [t3 stack](https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-app). You can use prisma with it for DB. Or if you would like to `mysql`.

If you want to continue using existing CRA app, then you can try [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/). It uses expressJS under the hood, and as you asked, comes with "Batteries included". Advantage would be that you can write your APIs with a lot less code.

There's also an option to use [cloud functions](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs&ved=2ahUKEwiBm_HHr8_5AhWu7jgGHVccAFkQjBB6BAgsEAM&usg=AOvVaw0LmuMyXgKmv9tWWe9yFxg9) offered by Google firebase. With it you can use firebase's [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore).

Ofcourse if you want super low latency across the world, you can also use [Cloudflare workers](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/).

These are all the options that I would personally consider, it might not have all the options available. These are only that I think are good alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @TheWhiteFang. I intend to research NextJS. I was looking at NextJS vs. Meteor articles earlier. How much effort is it to migrate from CRA to Next? Do I have to rewrite the frontend? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting point about SEO. The user's content would be behind a login. Therefore, I don't think I want or need SEO for the app itself. I'd want some kind of marketing / landing page for people to  see the product and hopefully decide to describe. That page would need SEO, but that would likely be a separate app.

Comment: There are other benefits of using next other than SEO. Next makes your pages load faster, and lower First Contentful Paint. If done right, the application becomes quite responsive. Of course, there might be some cases where SPAs make more sense.

Comment: Good point. Apart from the rendering / SEO optimizations, the other significant thing I see are the routes. To me this looks a lot like Express. So If I were considering using Express, Next would appear be a better choice. With Next I'd be getting the routes, which is mostly what Express does,  but I'd also be getting the render optimizations. In either case, I'd still have to pick out a DB and an auth package and configure those. I'm guessing the wiring up part would be the same whether I used those with Express or Next?

Comment: Well for auth you can use next-auth, it takes care of most of the things for you. And as for database you could use prisma. Prisma has a free tier that you can use to get a feel for things. And there's also a package called tRPC,  you might want to take a look at it.

Comment: I think you just sold me!

Comment: Well if you want more, the t3 stack that I mentioned earlier includes all of it. Basically it's a tool like CRA but for all the things you want to use. I don't use it because I like much fine control over the things I write but it is so convenient and perfect for the projects that I don't want to have custom things.

Comment: Interesting. Are there any specific limitations you run into when you use it? I'm wondering how much control I need... Also, is there an "eject" if you start out with it and run into a limitation later?

Comment: There aren't such limitations. Not that I am aware of. The reason I can't use it is a few, I am working on an old application and don't want to rewrite it, or I am using a different backend that is shared by other applications, or I am trying to optimize the code in a really really nonstandard way.